# vim search wildcard match first occurrence

Tags: regex, search, vim

I have a file that 
`<a href="blah.com" rel="blahblah" style="textdecoration:none;">blah</a>`

I want to match `rel="blahblah"`

but when i do `\rel=".*"` it matches `rel="blahblah" style="textdecoration:none;"`

I have tried `rel=".*\{-\}"` but that gives an error `nested \{`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use:

```
rel=".\{-}"
```

`\{-}` is used for non-greedy match in VIM

Comment: This is super useful when I don't want to match the longest string but the first one. Thansk a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

Try `[^"]` instead of `.`. The latter is "greedy" and will match as many characters as possible.

The `[d-r13579]` in regexps is used to match "character classes": in this case any small case letter in the range from `d` to `r` or an odd digit. If you start the class with a `^` then it negates the meaning.

Thus `[^"]` means a character except a double quote, and `"[^"]*"` means two double quotes with any number of arbitrary characters between them, except double quotes.

Comment: could you expand on that? I tried `/rel="[^"]` and that just returned `rel="b`

Comment: @mazlix I meant `/rel="[^"]*"`. You need the asterisk to match everything in the quotes.

Comment: oh.. so what's the `[^"]` do exactly?.. i thought the `"` in there was to represent the fact that i'm looking for a closing `"`

Comment: @mazlix I added the explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

By default regex matchers are greedy.

```
  s/rel=".\{-}"/aaaaaaa/
```

works for me

{-} means short circuit the expression  to match the shortest pattern.

Comment: it says pattern not found and if i escape the ? `:/rel=".*\?"` it says `Nested \?`

Comment: my apologies, I used the perl syntax first before I realised vi uses another syntax. I learned again something new, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find the use of `\{-}` confusing, so in cases like this I'll usually go for something like `/rel="[^"]*"`.